# How to change the line output when a VBA code reaches line 1,048,576

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to run a code that shows all the possible combinations when 8 dice are rolled. The problem is: there's almost 1.7million combinations and excel only has 1,048,576 lines, so VBA keeps giving me an error (Run-time error '1004': Method 'Offset' of object 'Range' failed) on this line:

```
Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)))
```

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my entire code:

```
Sub combinations()

Dim c1() As Variant
Dim c2() As Variant
Dim c3() As Variant
Dim c4() As Variant
Dim c5() As Variant
Dim c6() As Variant
Dim c7() As Variant
Dim c8() As Variant
Dim out() As Variant
Dim j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r As Long


Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range
Dim col3 As Range
Dim col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range
Dim col6 As Range
Dim col7 As Range
Dim col8 As Range
Dim out1 As Range


Set col1 = Range("A1:A6")
Set col2 = Range("B1:B6")
Set col3 = Range("C1:C6")
Set col4 = Range("D1:D6")
Set col5 = Range("E1:E6")
Set col6 = Range("F1:F6")
Set col7 = Range("G1:G6")
Set col8 = Range("H1:H6")

c1 = col1
c2 = col2
c3 = col3
c4 = col4
c5 = col5
c6 = col6
c7 = col7
c8 = col8

Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)))
out = out1

j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1
n = 1
o = 1
p = 1
q = 1
r = 1


Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                Do While n <= UBound(c5)
                    Do While o <= UBound(c6)
                        Do While p <= UBound(c7)
                            Do While q <= UBound(c8)
                            out(r, 1).Offset(0, Z) = c1(j, 1)
                            out(r, 2).Offset(0, Z) = c2(k, 1)
                            out(r, 3).Offset(0, Z) = c3(l, 1)
                            out(r, 4).Offset(0, Z) = c4(m, 1)
                            out(r, 5).Offset(0, Z) = c5(n, 1)
                            out(r, 6).Offset(0, Z) = c6(o, 1)
                            out(r, 7).Offset(0, Z) = c7(p, 1)
                            out(r, 8).Offset(0, Z) = c8(q, 1)
                            r = r + 1
                            If r > 1000000 Then
                            r = 1: Z = 10
                            End If
                            q = q + 1
                        Loop
                        q = 1
                        p = p + 1
                    Loop
                    p = 1
                    o = o + 1
                Loop
                o = 1
                n = n + 1
            Loop
            n = 1
            m = m + 1
        Loop
        m = 1
        l = l + 1
    Loop
    l = 1
    k = k + 1
Loop
k = 1
j = j + 1
out = out1
Loop

out1.Value = out
End Sub
```

How do I change it so that when it reaches line 1,048,576, it should start running the permutations in a different set of columns? Ideally, I would like it to start running the code in columns T2 - AA2 once J2 - Q2 have been filled.

Comment: I gave you an idea when you firstly asked the same question... Didn't it help? At least, did you understand what was it about?

Comment: When I ran the code you gave me it said "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch". It was in the line: acceptR = UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)

Comment: @FaneDuru I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I would say, you should ask... Try changing the next declaration: `acceptR As Long` with `acceptR As Double`.

Comment: And, also, change `Const maxR As Long = 1048575` in `Const maxR As Long = 1048574' . Your range starts from the second row...

Comment: Consider NOT filling the whole entire column, Excel doesn't like having data in every single row. Also... consider storing the data in a text (CSV?) file or an actual database instead of an Excel worksheet. Nearing or busting the maximum number of rows of a worksheet is a tell-tale sign that you're misusing or abusing something.

Comment: It's still giving me the same run-time error on that line.

Comment: Lastly, any time you declare `thing1`, `thing2`, `thing3`, ...`thingN`, what you really want is `things(0 To N-1)`

Comment: Do you address to me? If yes, please use: @FaneDuru. Did you change 'acceptR As Double'?

Comment: And I cannot understand the meaning of `out = out1` before of the last loop. It looks, clear everything you loaded in the array...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, I changed 'acceptR As Double' and  'Const maxR As Long = 1048575'. I still get the same error for some reason.

Comment: `Const maxR As Long = 1048574`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, please. I initially tried to only answer your question. Now, I also adapted a little your code. Please, try it for the ranges you showed us in the question. If you will increase them, the code must be adapted (not very complicated) to also use other arrays and maybe drop the arrays content in some .csv files. Please, test it as it is and confirm that this is what you wanted achieving.

```
Sub combinations()
Dim c1() As Variant, c2() As Variant, c3() As Variant, c4() As Variant
Dim c5() As Variant, c6() As Variant, c7() As Variant, c8() As Variant

Dim j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long
Dim o As Long, p As Long, q As Long, r As Long

Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, col3 As Range, col4 As Range
Dim col5 As Range, col6 As Range, col7 As Range, col8 As Range
Dim out1 As Range, out() As Variant

Set col1 = Range("A1:A6"): Set col2 = Range("B1:B6")
Set col3 = Range("C1:C6"): Set col4 = Range("D1:D6")
Set col5 = Range("E1:E6"): Set col6 = Range("F1:F6")
Set col7 = Range("G1:G6"): Set col8 = Range("H1:H6")

c1 = col1: c2 = col2: c3 = col3: c4 = col4
c5 = col5: c6 = col6: c7 = col7: c8 = col8

'___________________________________________________________________________
 Dim out2 As Range, outBis As Variant, acceptR As Double, boolNext As Double
 Const maxR As Long = 1048574
 acceptR = UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5) * UBound(c6) * UBound(c7) * UBound(c8)

 If acceptR > maxR Then
    Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(maxR))
    Set out2 = Range("T2", Range("AA2").Offset(acceptR - maxR))
    out = out1.value
    outBis = out2.value ' only for easy array dimensstoning
 Else
    Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("Q2").Offset(acceptR))
    out = out1.value
 End If
 '_______________________________________________________________________________
j = 1: k = 1: l = 1: m = 1: n = 1: o = 1: p = 1: q = 1: r = 1

Do While j <= UBound(c1)
    Do While k <= UBound(c2)
        Do While l <= UBound(c3)
            Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                Do While n <= UBound(c5)
                    Do While o <= UBound(c6)
                        Do While p <= UBound(c7)
                            Do While q <= UBound(c8)
                                If Not boolNext Then
                                    out(r, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                                    out(r, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                                    out(r, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                                    out(r, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                                    out(r, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                                    out(r, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                                    out(r, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                                    out(r, 8) = c8(q, 1)
                                    r = r + 1
                                    q = q + 1
                                    If r = maxR Then boolNext = True : r = 1
                                Else
                                    outBis(r, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 5) = c5(n, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 6) = c6(o, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 7) = c7(p, 1)
                                    outBis(r, 8) = c8(q, 1)
                                    r = r + 1
                                    q = q + 1
                                End If
                            Loop
                            q = 1
                            p = p + 1
                        Loop
                        p = 1
                        o = o + 1
                    Loop
                    o = 1
                    n = n + 1
                Loop
                n = 1
                m = m + 1
            Loop
            m = 1
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        l = 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = 1
    j = j + 1
Loop

out1.value = out
If UBound(outBis) > 1 Then out2.value = outBis
End Sub
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help and patience, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @B.Straatman: Glad to here that! But, a (free) piece of advice: When somebody spends some time in order to help you, it is, at least, polite to have a comment saying what does not work as you wish... And something else: Wen a code does what you need, it is recommended to tick the code left check box, to make it accepted answer. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will rapidly know that it worked...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry I didn't acknowledge your original answer to my problem. I clicked the uptick because that's all I thought was necessary, but I've now clicked the checkmark to make it clear the problem was solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this with Excel, I will propose you my idea and you will tell me if it is feasible with your project.

The basic intuition is that 6 to the power of 4 is obviously more manageable than 6 to the power of 8. So I would divide the 8 dice in two. The first four will be a "Fixed Part" (red in the picture) and the second four will be a "Mobile Part"(grey and white in the picture). Every row will give you all the possible  combinations of each "Fixed Part" with the other four dice. The first four columns will give you all the possible combinations of the "Fixed Part".

As a Result you will have the following spreadsheet of 1296 Rows and  5184 = (1296 * 4) Columns:

[image: 8 Dice Combination Spreadsheet]

***Code***:

```
Sub EightDiceCombinations()
Dim FourDiceArray()
Dim i, j, k, l As Long
Dim FxNRow As Long
Dim MbNRow, MbNCol As Long

FxNRow = 1
MbNCol = 5

For i = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 6
        For k = 1 To 6
            For l = 1 To 6

                FourDiceArray = Array(i, j, k, l)
                'MsgBox Join(FourDiceArray, " ")__TEST

                'Fill Fixed Part
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FxNRow, 1), Cells(FxNRow, 4)).Value = FourDiceArray

                'Fill Mobile Part
                For MbNRow = 1 To 1296 '(6 to the power of 4)
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MbNRow, MbNCol), Cells(MbNRow, MbNCol + 3)).Value = FourDiceArray
                Next MbNRow

                MbNCol = MbNCol + 4
                FxNRow = FxNRow + 1

            Next l
        Next k
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

On a side note, you can always retrieve a EightDice combination with a composition of random functions: Random("Fixed Part") & Random("Mobile Part").

I hope this solution could be of help for your purposes.

Comment: I never got a chance to run this code because the one above worked in solving my problem. Thanks for your time!